# CSS hover doesn't work in the div with relative position

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem. I have this code [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbsgnopc/1/)

```
<div class="row header">

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sd-2 logo">
    <h2>HEADLINE</h2>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="description">

  <div class="about">O NÁS</div>

</div>
```

Don't ask me about the positions. I've got this for some dropped shadow. But I really don't know why nothing, that I put in the area of the red div is active. Hover doesn't work, links doesn't work. Nothing!...could you help me please?

Comment: where is your hover class?

Comment: There aren't any hover effects or links in your fiddle

Comment: ou sorry I mean :active for the button. But :hover doesn't work also and also links. Everything I put in the red div behave like it's not there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `z-index:-100` on `div.description` is causing a problem. Consider removing it. Looks like any negative value here is causing this weird behaviour.

I am wandering - have you tried this code outside of JSFiddle? Perhaps there is a z-index conflict inside of JSFiddle iFrame which, hides this element "below" other DOM nodes generated by JSFiddle

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row header">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sd-2 logo">
         <h2>HEADLINE</h2>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="description">
    <div class="about">O NÁS</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
h2 {
    color: #664F34;
}
.header {
    color: #664F34;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.cases {
    font-family: AktivGrotesk-Black;
}
.description {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
.about {
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f5cf9f;
    border: 1px solid #e3c095;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    right: 160px;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
.about:hover {
    background:salmon;
}
.description:hover {
    background:blue;
}
.about:active {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    color: black;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbsgnopc/3/)